# How do I use a combo box to display information based on the user's selection?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, excel-2010

I have a combo box with a few different selections:

```
Selection 1 
Selection 2 
Selection 3
```

Now I know that once I make a selection it will return a number in whichever cell I specify:

```
1
2
3
```

Now let's say that I have a =SUMIFS function in the following format:

```
=SUMIFS(Data!$G:$G,Data!$A:$A,Account!$B$6,Data!$B:$B,">=" & C5,Data!$B:$B, "<=" & D5)
```

Now I have a separate sheet that is my "database" or raw data that I'm using to populate these cells with data. So if you look at the

```
Data!$G:$G (which is the column that I'm summing)
```

Is there a way to either way to sum up a specific column based on the combo box selection in the =SUMIFS formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your combo box to choose the column letter is in A1:

```
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Data!" & $A$1 & ":" & $A$1),Data!$A:$A,Account!$B$6,Data!$B:$B,">=" & C5,Data!$B:$B, "<=" & D5)
```

This is, of course, assuming the combo box lets you actually select the letter. If the selections are something else and you want the letter hidden from the user, perhaps make a hidden cell somewhere that has a nested IF statement resulting in the column letter tied to each selection, then have the formula above reference that cell.

Comment: Yeah, this perfect! And rather than concatenating "Data!" & ":" cellReference I just kept it all together Data!H:H (example). I was having issues with the way you showed me. It led me in the right direction, though. Thanks!